# multi-row update table with "different" data

Tags: sql, oracle

I think the best way to explain this is to tell you what I have.

I have two tables A and B both have columns Field1 and Field2. However Field 2 is not populated in table B

I want to populate field 2 of table B with field 2 of table A where field 1 of table A matches field 1 of table B.

something like update tableB set Field2 = tableA.field2 where tablea.field1 = tableb.field1.

The reason this may seem so odd and obscure is that I'm tyring to do an inital data load form an old database to a new one.

please let me know if you need clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just need a correlated update

```
UPDATE tableB b
   SET field2 = (SELECT a.field2
                   FROM tableA a
                  WHERE a.field1 = b.field1 )
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
                 FROM tableA a
                WHERE a.field1 = b.field1 );
```

Since every `field2` in B is NULL to begin with, you may be able to skip the WHERE EXISTS (in which case rows in B that don't have a match in A would be updated with a NULL generating a bit of extra redo).  But you would generally want to include that so that you only update rows where there is a match.

Comment: this worked if I left out the where exists clause, this that clause it did not insert any rows.

Comment: what if i also wanted to link to a field in a third tableC. I want to link TableA.Field1 to tableC.Field1 and only aply the update when tableC.field3 = 'Y'

Comment: @kralco626 - If no rows were updated when you included the WHERE EXISTS, then no rows would have been updated to a non-NULL value if the WHERE EXISTS was present.  Are you certain that the data in FIELD1 matches between the two tables?

Comment: @kralco626 - I'm not completely sure that I follow how tableC relates.  Do you still want b.field2 updated with the value from a.field2?  But only if there is a matching row in tableC as well?  It would probably clarify things if you could update your question with some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: @Justin - your right, that other table had not yet been populated. I populated it and then it worked with the exsists clause. However my subquery is returning multiple rows, so I have to look into my data and see why I have multiple rows for the same value of Field1.

Comment: @justin - no, I want to check tablec. if table tablec.field3 <> 'CN' then don't preformt he update at all. tableC also contains field1.